# Can't record camera mp4 on External storage in android post 4.3

Tags: android

I have a permission exception when I try (I think) to create a file in my physical device's external storage (nexus 5 android 6.0), whereas it works fine with a 4.3 emulated device. 
My permissions are fine, but I get this error :

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.media.action.VIDEO_CAPTURE flg=0x3 cmp=com.google.android.GoogleCamera/com.android.camera.VideoCamera clip={text/uri-list U:file:///storage/emulated/0/Pictures/MyCameraApp/VID_20151216_145322.mp4} (has extras) } from ProcessRecord{5dab894 22712:com.***} (pid=22712, uid=10199) with revoked permission android.permission.CAMERA
```

any idea ?

I'll add a little more information :

My media utils is basic copy/paste from google video tutorial :

```
public class MediaUtils {

    public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE = 1;
    public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO = 2;

    /** Create a file Uri for saving an image or video */
    public static Uri getOutputMediaFileUri(int type){
        return Uri.fromFile(getOutputMediaFile(type));
    }

    /** Create a File for saving an image or video */
    public static File getOutputMediaFile(int type){
        // To be safe, you should check that the SDCard is mounted
        // using Environment.getExternalStorageState() before doing this.

        File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "MyCameraApp");
        // This location works best if you want the created images to be shared
        // between applications and persist after your app has been uninstalled.

        // Create the storage directory if it does not exist
        if (! mediaStorageDir.exists()){
            if (! mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()){
                Log.d("MyCameraApp", "failed to create directory");
                return null;
            }
        }

        // Create a media file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        File mediaFile;
        if (type == MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE){
            mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator +
                    "IMG_"+ timeStamp + ".jpg");
        } else if(type == MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO) {
            mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File

                    .separator +
                    "VID_"+ timeStamp + ".mp4");
        } else {
            return null;
        }

        return mediaFile;
    }

}
```

And my intent :

```
Uri fileUri = MediaUtils.getOutputMediaFileUri(MediaUtils.MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO);
Intent takeVideoIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
takeVideoIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);

startActivityForResult(takeVideoIntent, ACTION_TAKE_VIDEO);
```

Comment: Are you sure that you get this on Android 5.x devices, and not just Android 6.0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a new permission system on API 23 and higher.
The permission is requested at run time.

You should read this [How to manage permission on Android 6.0](http://www.howtogeek.com/230683/how-to-manage-app-permissions-on-android-6.0/) and this [Android request permission](http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)

Comment: hum, give me a sec I check if it works on android 5.00

Comment: One of the most stupid implementations google could come up with..Absolutely useless and causes so many problems for developers..